# Data Protector: When migrating StoreOnce, how to "scan" the media?

Tags: import, media, data-protector

Being in the process to migrate the clients to a new cell (also changing the port from 5555 to 5565) I added a File Jukebox to the new cell, configure the repository files, and then scanned and imported those.
That took a while, but succeeded.

When migrating StoreOnce, I basically did the same, used the existing Store, but in the new cell I see no media repository or media slots, etc.

So I wonder (how) can I import the media in the Store to the new cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the slot objects of the StoreOnce have to be imported to the IDB (Internal DataBase) so that they can be scanned or imported.

There are different commands to do that, and there is a helpful article that suggests how to do that with script: [(DP) Support Tip: Importing media from a StoreOnce store.](https://community.microfocus.com/img/bandr/f/itrc-251/161710/dp-support-tip-importing-media-from-a-storeonce-store)

Basically you use `omnib2d -list_objects` and the `-b2ddevice` option to get the slots listed that StoreOnce knows.
The script computes the difference between the slots known by IDB and the slots known by StoreOnce.

Then you can "import the slots" to IDB using `omnimm -add_slots`.
After that you could use the GUI to mark the slots to scan them or to import the media, or you could use the command `omnimm -import` with option `-slot` to import the media in the specific slot to the IDB.

I did everything with an adapted script, but the actual media import is rather verbose (like 30 lines output per medium), so I'd better do that from the GUI, as it captures the output for later review.

I plan to put my adapted script to github next week (if time permits).